# MySQL: Is there a way to transform string formats?

Tags: mysql, format

**EDIT:**
Please don't focus on the value it self. I'm well aware of that I should save such a value as float or decimal. It's not about saving integer as string etc. It's about changing the format of a given string, independently of what it represents.

Lets say, I have different tables, with different formats of currency.

In table 1, the format is "1.20$".

In table 2, the format is "$ 1,20".

In table 3, the format is "1$ 20c"

I want to unify those formats to a different one, lets say "1$$20$". **Of course this makes not a lot of sense, but it's about transforming a string, not about extracting the value. Also, the goal is not to transform them all together in one step, it is about changing formats into other formats at all.**

Of course, I could load the the column in chucks into memory and transform them step by step with php or alternative languages, but I was curious if there is another way.

So, is there a way to transforming strings to other strings? More or less, "if match pattern, transform to other pattern"? What would you recommend, in terms of processing time?

Comment: I'd recommend storing them all as integers. Do the formatting at the presentation layer.

Comment: Or you can store them using a [fixed-point type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) – either way, store them as numbers, because that's what they are. Your *data*base should contain *data*, not formatting.

Comment: Please don't focus on the value it self. I'm well aware of that. It's not about saving integer as string etc. Its about changing the format of a given string

Comment: Yes that was the question. So it seems there is none and there are better ways. Thanks, if you post it. i will accept it.

Comment: **Cleanup the numbers _before_ storing them.**